# How can I calculate using COUNTIFS and SUMPRODUCT before TODAY?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large spreadsheet that contains a lot of football match results from many leagues. It contains every match for the past few seasons including the current season. Each row contains a match and there are roughly 11000 rows per season. I am trying to calculate various statistics from this data for each team.

For the current season database, there are all of fixtures for this season, so that means that there are some future fixtures that have not been played yet so have no data. I have a 'Team Sheet' that contains a list of all of the teams in the database and i have formulae that goes through the database sheet and when the team is found it takes that data and calculates things. The database has the following columns:

Column A - COUNTRY
Column B - SEASON
Column C - DATE
Column D - TIME
Column E - ROUND
Column F - Home Team
Column G - Away Team
Columns H:AA - Various GOAL DATA

I would like to add to my formulae on the 'Team Sheet' to ignore any fixtures that are after `TODAY` (Column C on the database sheet)

Currently i use `COUNTIFS` and `SUMPRODUCT` to make my calculations.

Here is an example of a calculation:

`=IFERROR(IF($D4="","",COUNTIFS('DATABASE 19-20'!$F:$F,$D4,'DATABASE 19-20'!$AG:$AG,">=2")/$E4),"")`

Here is what i have tried to make it only calculate the data if it is from before `TODAY`

`=IFERROR(IF($D4="","",COUNTIFS('DATABASE 19-20'!$F:$F,$D4,'DATABASE 19-20'!$C:$C,"<"&TODAY(),'DATABASE 19-20'!$AG:$AG,">=2")/$E4),"")`

This however does not work.

Here is a screenshot of the database:

[image: databse]

And here is a screenshot of the Team Sheet

[image: teamsheet]

I am happy to provide my spreadsheet if it helps.

Comment: tl;dr please simplify the example to the smallest amount of data needed to understand the problem; [mcve]

Comment: Please provide some sample data and demonstrate how you would like to **ignore any fixtures that are after TODAY**? How can you have fixture results beyond today if they have not yet happened?

Comment: Try including the NOW() function in your countifs() as less than etc